# Linear Sweep of a 2D Polygon

Tags: geometry, algorithms, area, plane-geometry, polygons

Suppose we have a 2D simple polygon (no self-intersection) on the $XY$ plane defined by $n$ vertices and a 2D vector $V=(A,B)$.
Is there an algorithm to detect if a generic point $P=(x,y)$ on the plane belongs to the area that is covered by the polygon when it "slides" along the line segment from $A$ to $B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generated region is the so-called ["Minkovski sum"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) $P'= P \oplus V$ of the polygon and the vector (that can be considered as a degenerated polygon). $P'$ is known to be still a (convex) polygon.

Therefore, the algorithm you are looking for amounts to combine 2 classical algorithms :

- The [algorithm](https://vnspoj.github.io/wiki/geometry/minkowski) giving the vertices of this Minkowski sum $P'$.
- The [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1119627/5802041) testing whether a point is inside or outside a convex polygon .

Comment: Hi Jean, Thank you for your answer. Do yo mind sharing some algorithm reference for the Minkovski sum?

Comment: I have made an edit including references.

Comment: Is there something about non-convex polygons?

Comment: For non-convex polygons, you have to use the crossing number method, described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: This answers a different question, for when the sliding vector is "infinitely large".**

The area covered by the sliding polygon is an infinite strip which has two bounding lines. To find out which two vertices $(x_i,y_i)$ of the polygon are the ones sliding along the boundary, you can maximize/minimize the following function:
$$
\alpha(x_i,y_i) := -B x_i + A y_i
$$
where $(A,B)$ is the direction of the sliding. Geometrically, this formula comes from taking the scalar product of $(x_i,y_i)$ with the vector $(-B,A)$ perpendicular to $(A,B)$.
Once you have the maximum index $i_{max}$ and minimum index $i_{min}$, a point $(x,y)$ lies in the region if and only if
$$
\alpha(x_{i_{min}},y_{i_{min}}) \leq \alpha(x,y) \leq \alpha(x_{i_{max}},y_{i_{max}}). 
$$

Comment: I don't understand the question as saying the polygon slides along an "infinite strip". I think we have a polygon P(0), and a vector AB, and we consider the region covered by the union of all polygons P(t) = P(0) + t AB for t in [0, 1].

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant. The sweep is not along an infinite line but along a finite segment from A to B.

Comment: Oh you are right. I think I misunderstood the question.