# Locus of vector endpoint

Tags: geometry, locus

Let u and v be two vectors, with their starting point at the center O of the square ABCD, and their endpoints moving along the sides of the square. Determine the locus of the endpoint of u + v!

This is what I got so far:

$u =\begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $v = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix}$,  then $u + v = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 + v_1 \\ u_2 + v_2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Now let's take

$A = (-2a, 2a), B = (-2a, 0), C = (0, 0), D = (0, 2a)$.

Then, the coordinates of the O center is $O=(-a,a)$

My intuition tells me that the locus of the $u+v$ vector endpoint is going to be a circle.

How can I prove this?

Comment: make a drawing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this set is a (filled) square (blue line in the figure below) with sidelength doubled with respect to the initial square (in black). It is called the **Minkowski addition** of the two shapes. It is known that the Minkowski sum of two polygonal shapes is a polygonal shape.

More precisely, the Minkowski sum of two shapes $A \oplus B$ can be thought as the shape resulting of the sweeping (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4636401/305862)) of the center of shape $A$ along shape $B$, which indeed gives, in the present case, a filled square with a doubled side.

Here is a graphical representation with 5000 instances of the vector's sum (red points) covering the (big) square.

[image]

Here is the Matlab program that has generated the figure (please note how function $f$ encodes - with complex numbers - the initial square)

> ```
> clear all;close all;axis equal;
> f=@(t)(exp(i*t)./(abs(cos(t))+abs(sin(t)))); % square
> for k=1:5000;
>    t1=2*pi*rand;t2=2*pi*rand;
>    T(k)=f(t1)+f(t2); % vector sum
> end;
> plot(T,'.r');
> t=0:0.01:2*pi;
> plot(f(t),'k'); % black square
> plot(2*f(t),'b'); % blue square
> ```

Comment: A similar (very recent !) question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4811783/305862).

Answer (score 3):

Jean Marie has pointed out the answer. What follows is a proof using elementary concepts.

For simplicity, let the coordinates of the original square $ABCD$ be $A(1,-1), B(1,1), C(-1,1)$ and $D(-1,-1)$.

Then our vectors have the form: $(1, \beta), (-1, \beta), (\alpha, 1),$ and $(\alpha, -1)$, where $-1 \leq \alpha, \beta \leq 1.$

[image]

Let $S$ be our set of vectors with endpoints on square $ABCD.$

Let $T$ be the set of vectors with end point on or inside square $EFGH$ as shown in the figure.

Then $$T= \{ (x,y): -2 \leq x, y \leq 2. \}$$

We are going to prove that the sum of any $2$ vectors of $S$ is a vector in $T$, and conversely any vector in $T$ is the sum of $2$ vectors in $S$.

Proof:
$ \Rightarrow$ direction

Vectors of $S$ have the form: $(1, \beta), (-1, \beta), (\alpha, 1),$ and $(\alpha, -1)$, where $-1 \leq \alpha, \beta \leq 1.$

$$\therefore (x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)  \in S \implies -1 \leq x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2 \leq 1.$$ This implies that$$-2 \leq x_1+y_1, x_2+y_2 \leq 2.$$
Hence $$(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)=(x_1+y_1, x_2+y_2) \in T.$$

Thus the sum of any $2$ vectors in $S$ belongs to $T$.

$$$$
$\Leftarrow$ direction

Conversely, for any vectors $(x,y) \in T$, we consider $4$ different cases, corresonding to the $4$ quadrants in which $(x, y)$ lies.

Case $(1)$ $(x,y)$ lies in quadrant $1$.

Then $$0 \leq x, y \leq 2 \implies -1 \leq x-1, y-1 \leq 1,$$
$$(1,y-1), (x-1,1) \in S$$
and
$$(1,y-1 )+(x-1,1)=(x,y).$$
Thus $(x,y)$ is the sum of $2$ vectors in $S$.
$$$$
Case $(2)$ $(x,y)$ lies in quadrant $2$.

Then $-2 \leq x \leq 0$ and $0 \leq y \leq 2$

This implies that $-1 \leq 1+x \leq 1$ and $-1 \leq y-1 \leq 1$ and hence
$(1+x,1), (-1, y-1) \in S$.

$$\because (1+x,1)+(-1, y-1)=(x,y),$$
$\therefore (x,y)$ is the sum of 2 vectors in $S$.

Cases in other quadrants are similar.